# When is a practice said to be Haraam

Tags: sharia

Asalamu Alaikum
Please On whose authority is something/practice forbiden considered Haraam;Allah SWT, the prohet Alaihim Salam or from both.

Answer (score 2):

God alone is the one who can decree anything as *haram*.  But given that God's forbiddances are done through the words and actions of the prophet — the messenger of God — what the prophet declares *haram* is considered so done under and with God's full authority.

The Hanafi school makes a distinction between *Haram* (forbidden) and *Makruh Tahrim* (prohibitively disliked).  Only those acts which are indisputably forbidden (e.g. via Qur'an or *mutawattir* ahadith) are classified as *haram*.

Acts which are (apparently) prohibited by the prophet, but which fail to reach the criteria of *mutawattir*, are classified as *makruh tahrim*.  Such acts are still effectively forbidden and considered sinful, but if one refuses to accept the ruling it would not be considered as rejecting Islam as such rulings are based on speculative (rather than definitive) evidence.

To the best of my knowledge, this is unique to the Hanafis; other schools make no such distinction and treat all such as mutually *haram*.